# ElementNotVisibleException : Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have checked all previous similar issues, they are not applicable to my case.

```
   try:
      element = wait.until(
      EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='_ariaId_73.folder'] | //*[@id='_ariaId_133.folder']"))
   )
   except: 
      print "403 : Monitoring Not Found"

element.click()
```

It is not going to enter into exception block also, but it is still throwing `ElementNotVisibleException` for `element.click()` method.

Comment: can you share url if possible ?

Comment: i didn't get you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few words about the solution:

1. Expected conditions with clause `presence_of_element_located()` relates  to *an expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. The locator used to find the element returns the WebElement once it is located*. Hence we have to change the clause from `presence_of_element_located()` to **`visibility_of_element_located()`** which relates *to an expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. element is the WebElement returns the (same) WebElement once it is visible*.
2. Moving forward you have tried to invoke `click()` method for the *WebElement*. So instead of `presence_of_element_located()` we will use the **`element_to_be_clickable()`** clause.
3. Here is your own code with minor changes :

   ```
   try:
       element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='_ariaId_73.folder'] | //*[@id='_ariaId_133.folder']")))
   except: 
       print "403 : Monitoring Not Found"
   element.click()
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.