# Why selenium code doesn't work every time?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

**I am currently working on this webpage:**

https://www.orbitz.com/Flights-Search?trip=oneway&leg1=from:Hong%20Kong,to:New%20York%20City,departure:01/01/2018TANYT&passengers=children:0,adults:1,seniors:0,infantinlap:Y&mode=search

**My code:**

```
#function for searching for all "details" button, return list
def search_detail_button():
    detail_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.show-flight-details")
    return (detail_buttons)

##Open all details pages
def open_details():
    time.sleep(3)
    for button in search_detail_button():
        button.click()
        time.sleep(1.5)

open_details()
```

**Expected result:**

All "Flight details and baggage fees" would be opened.

**Actual result:**

Sometimes it works, sometimes it gives me an exception.
Why would a code sometimes work, sometimes don't?

Comment: Which `exception` do you observe and at which line? Update the question with error stack trace.

Comment: Somehow I'm not getting any exception now after I lengthened the sleep time from 3 to 5. I believe the exception is "element not visible".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElementNotVisibleException : Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108512/elementnotvisibleexception-selenium-python)

Comment: I just got the exception: Element is not clickable.
Could it be the case that the elements moved in position?

Comment: For `Element is not clickable` see this QA -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Java. I am using Python.
The link you above seems to be for Java.