# Element not visible exception in Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to click a menu item from a navigation bar. I was able to click the first menu item and navigate to that page. But when I tried to navigate to other pages it always gives **ElementNotVisibleException**.

HTML for the menu items.

```
<ul id="yw1" class="dropdown-menu">
 <li id="people_add"><a tabindex="-1" href="/index.php/People/add"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x "></i> Add People</a></li>
 <li id="people_search"><a tabindex="-1" href="/index.php/people/search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-1x "></i> Search People</a></li>
 <li id="people_merge"><a tabindex="-1" href="/index.php/people/mergeDup"><i class="fa fa-user fa-1x "></i> Merge Duplicates</a></li>
 <li id="bulk_insert"><a tabindex="-1" href="/index.php/BulkInsert/Admin"><i class="fa fa-file fa-1x "></i> Bulk Insert</a></li>
 </ul>
```

This code works for the first menu item.

```
driver1.findElement(By.id("people_add")).click();
```

But It doesn't work for the second menu item or any other.

```
driver1.findElement(By.id("people_search")).click();
```

I tried the xpath for the second menu item. but it also didn't work.I still got element not visible exception again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `doesn't work`? Do you see any error? Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: is menu item visible always or will be visible only when mouse over on main menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElementNotVisibleException : Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108512/elementnotvisibleexception-selenium-python)

Comment: I guess there more than one element which id is 'people_search' and the first one is not visible. please confirm this by DevTool manaully to see css selector: #people_search can match how many elements on the problem page.

Comment: @yong I have only one people_search.

Comment: The problem was, I was trying to click the people_search without clicking the Main menu item "People". There for Selenium couldn't find the people_search element. Thank you for your feedback. It helped me to understand the mistake I have done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mutiple frames in your application then try to go to the default content before clicking the second menu item.

> driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
>
> driver1.findElement(By.id("people_search")).click();